# How to see the final script running with replaced values in Gitlab cicd

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I have a step in gitlab cicd like below

```yaml
.internal_deploy_cloud_run:
    variables:
        GCLOUD_COMMAND: ''
        GCP_SA: ''
        GCP_SA_NAME: ''
        GCP_PROJECT_ID: ''
        FINAL_CLOUD_RUN_NAME: ''
        REGION: 'us-central1'
        ALLOW_UNAUTHENTICATED: 'FALSE'
        ALLOW_UNAUTHENTICATED_PARAM: ''
        ENV_VARS: ''
        SECRET_VARS: ''
        SET_SECRET_PARAM: ''
        VPC_CONNECTOR: ''
        VPC_CONNECTOR_PARAM: ''
    stage: deploy
    image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
    before_script:
        - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $GCP_SA
        - gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
    script:
        - echo "Deploy to $GCP_PROJECT_ID"
        - gcloud run deploy $CLOUD_RUN_NAME --image gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$FINAL_CLOUD_RUN_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA --platform managed --region=$REGION $ALLOW_UNAUTHENTICATED_PARAM --set-env-vars "GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID=$GCP_PROJECT_ID,CLOUD_RUN_NAME=$CLOUD_RUN_NAME,CLOUD_RUN_LOCATION=$REGION,$ENV_VARS" $SET_SECRET_PARAM $VPC_CONNECTOR_PARAM --service-account=$GCP_SA_NAME
```

When I see the execution logs of step, commands are showing with some variables for example I see `gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID` in logs,

My question is how can I log the final command after variables replacement, for example in about case I expect to see `gcloud config set project my-project-1`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to

```
.internal_deploy_cloud_run:
    variables:
        GCLOUD_COMMAND: ''
        GCP_SA: ''
        GCP_SA_NAME: ''
        GCP_PROJECT_ID: ''
        FINAL_CLOUD_RUN_NAME: ''
        REGION: 'us-central1'
        ALLOW_UNAUTHENTICATED: 'FALSE'
        ALLOW_UNAUTHENTICATED_PARAM: ''
        ENV_VARS: ''
        SECRET_VARS: ''
        SET_SECRET_PARAM: ''
        VPC_CONNECTOR: ''
        VPC_CONNECTOR_PARAM: ''
    stage: deploy
    image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
    before_script:
        - |
            set -x
            gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $GCP_SA
            gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
    script:
        - |
            set -x
            echo "Deploy to $GCP_PROJECT_ID"
            gcloud run deploy $CLOUD_RUN_NAME --image gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$FINAL_CLOUD_RUN_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA --platform managed --region=$REGION $ALLOW_UNAUTHENTICATED_PARAM --set-env-vars "GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID=$GCP_PROJECT_ID,CLOUD_RUN_NAME=$CLOUD_RUN_NAME,CLOUD_RUN_LOCATION=$REGION,$ENV_VARS" $SET_SECRET_PARAM $VPC_CONNECTOR_PARAM --service-account=$GCP_SA_NAME
```